# I can not login phpmyadmin in windows

Tags: mysql

when I give a username and password in `localhost/phpmyadmin`, then it's not login and show again username and password window and I try again but the result is same.
I can not remember phpmyadmin username and password. So what can i do now or reset it?

Comment: what is your Operating system?

Answer (score 1):

if you're in Unix environment,change or reset your MySQL root password by doing the following:

**Stop the MySQL server:**

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

**Start mysqld:**

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

**Login to MySQL as root:**

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

**Change MYSECRET with your new root password:**

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('MYSECRET') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

**Kill mysqld:**

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

**Start mysql:**

```
sudo service mysql start
```

**Login to phpmyadmin as root with your new password**

and if you're using windows, then follow the instructions 
in the [link given HERE](http://www.jovicailic.org/2012/04/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password-under-windows/)